# Array of enums type in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, arrays, enums, clickhouse

In *ClickHouse 21.4* I created a table with array of enums column:

```
CREATE TABLE test_array_enum (
    id String,
    fixation_at DateTime64(3, 'UTC'),
    types Array(
        Enum(
            'FIRST_TYPE' = 1, 'SECOND_TYPE' = 2, 'THIRD_TYPE' = 3,
            'FOURTH_TYPE' = 4
        )
    )
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree
ORDER BY (fixation_at, id);
```

Fill some data:

```
INSERT INTO test_array_enum (id, fixation_at, types) VALUES ('1', now64(), []),
                                                            ('2', now64(), ['FIRST_TYPE']),
                                                            ('3', now64(), ['SECOND_TYPE', 'THIRD_TYPE']),
                                                            ('4', now64(), ['FOURTH_TYPE']);
```

I want to filter data by **types** column, query returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_array_enum
WHERE hasAny(types, ['SECOND_TYPE', 'THIRD_TYPE']);
```

It works fine with Int values:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_array_enum
WHERE hasAny(types, [2, 3]);
```

Is there a way to filter data by string values of enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test_array_enum
WHERE arrayFirstIndex(x -> x = 'SECOND_TYPE' OR x = 'THIRD_TYPE', types) > 0

/*
┌─id─┬─────────────fixation_at─┬─types────────────────────────┐
│ 3  │ 2021-07-08 02:11:21.238 │ ['SECOND_TYPE','THIRD_TYPE'] │
└────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfect. Actually `OR` can be replaced with `IN`: `WHERE arrayFirstIndex(x -> x IN ('SECOND_TYPE', 'THIRD_TYPE'), types) > 0`. I think it more preferably to generate that condition by code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cast if it has sense

```
SELECT *
FROM test_array_enum
WHERE hasAny(types, CAST(['SECOND_TYPE', 'THIRD_TYPE'], 'Array(Enum(\'FIRST_TYPE\' = 1, \'SECOND_TYPE\' = 2, \'THIRD_TYPE\' = 3, \'FOURTH_TYPE\' = 4))'))
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to store mapping between string and int values in code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

for my use case, dropping the `Array(Enum)` column and using `Array(LowCardinality(String))` was enough,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    l_versions Array(LowCardinality(String)),
    _timestamp DateTime DEFAULT now()
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(_timestamp)
      PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(_timestamp)
      ORDER BY (_timestamp)
      TTL _timestamp + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;

INSERT INTO test(l_versions)
VALUES (array('v1', 'v3'));

SELECT * FROM test WHERE hasAny(l_versions,['v2']);
```